# Custom multithread service in Rails app

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, multithreading

I'm develop RoR app and I need to create some background service which should work with my base and controllers. I have a class with thread which must doing some work with queue. So that we have:

```
class ServerThread

   def initialize(name)
       @name = name
       @queue = Queue.new
       @thread = Thread.new do
          while true
              if @queue.empty?
                  Thread.stop
              end
              item = @queue.pop
              log = `run #{item}` 
              save_log(log)    #save into DB
          end    
       end
   end

   def add_to_queue(item)
       @queue << item
       @thread.run
   end

end
```

and now it's working like this. I just create global variable in some file:

```
$threads = SomeService.new
Server.all.each do |server|                    #servers from DB
    $threads << ServerThread.new(server.name)
end
```

And some times browser user add items to queue by controller:

```
class ServerController < ApplicationController

   def add_to_queue       
       $threads.get_thread_by_name(params['server']).add_to_queue(params['item'])       
       render :nothing => true
   end    

end
```

I have some users which add items to queue and I need watch for all threads on my app. 
I need create this $threads when I start my rails app and this threads should be common for all browser users. Now I trying deploy my app with apache2 and passenger, so this's global variable don't work!

How to do it without a global variable?

RoR 3.2, ruby 1.9.2

Comment: You should look into background processing gems, like Resque or Sidekiq. Manual thread pool is a bad idea (especially in MRI which has crippled threads).

Comment: +1 for Sidekiq, this will almost certainly do a better job than writing something from scratch.

Comment: I suggest [Delayed::Job](https://github.com/collectiveidea/delayed_job), it lets you avoid to maintain a whole new db service (like Redis or something else), which in the most cases is an unneeded complication

Comment: I'll try to pay attention to these gems, but it would be interesting to understand the mechanism of rails and figure out how to write it from scratch. The idea is that I already have everything I need, but I just do not know where and how to connect it: (

Answer (score 0):

like @Sergio already stated. it would be a good idea not to write something like this from scratch. writing concurrent programs reliably is not one of the simplest task to do and really hard to debug. there are some really good alternatives available in ruby. have a look at the ruby-toolbox: https://www.ruby-toolbox.com/categories/Background_Jobs

if you reaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaly want to do it by yourself, then you have to replace your global variable with something that can be shared by multiple processes on the same or even different machines. i think that a really simple solution to this problem would be to use the queueing functionality of redis and implement your background worker on top of that.

Comment: Can you help me, how do it with Resque gem? I lost 2 days to understand how it work, but still can't realize it in my case.

Comment: if you have a specific question concerning resque, please go ahead and create a new question.